Can't get notification values in .NET MAUI Android app when tapping a group of notifications while the app is in background
I am building an Android app using .NET MAUI. The app receives push notifications from Google's Firebase. I have trouble getting multiple notifications data when my app is in background.
When multiple notifications appear in the drawer while the app is in background or closed (killed) state, they are sort of grouped as if there is one notification (image below). If I tap the "grouped" notification without expanding it, intent?.HasExtra("body") returns false in MainActivity - OnNewIntent() (see the code below). I tried Intent.HasExtra("body") (capital I) but it also returns false. OnNewIntent() runs only once.

Because HasExtra(<key>) returns false, I can't get any values of those notifications at all. I don't know how to access the values of them. How do I get them??
If there is one single notification in the drawer and it's tapped while the app is in background, I can get the values of the notification. intent?.HasExtra("body") returns true.
Additionally, I can get the values of a notification if I expand the group (image below) and tap one notification at a time.

Here is my code:
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity, Android.Gms.Tasks.IOnSuccessListener
{
    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        DeviceInstallationService.Token = result.ToString();
    }

    // this method is called when a notification in drawer is tapped while the app is in background
    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        ProcessNotificationsAction(intent);
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (DeviceInstallationService.NotificationsSupported)
            FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken().AddOnSuccessListener(this);

        ProcessNotificationsAction(Intent);
    }

    private void ProcessNotificationsAction(Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (intent?.HasExtra("body") == true)
                {
                    var body = intent.GetStringExtra("body");

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
                    {
                        var id = Guid.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("id"));
                        var application = intent.GetStringExtra("application");
                        var datePublished = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("datePublished")), DateTimeKind.Utc);
                        NotificationMessageService.TriggerMessage(id, application, body, intent.HasExtra("url") ? intent.GetStringExtra("url") : null, datePublished);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

This is what I send from Firebase:
{
  "message": {
    "notification": {
      "title": "Notification title",
      "body": "This is a test message..."
    },
    "android": {
      "notification": {
        "channel_id": "com.company.app.default"
      }
    },
    "data": {
      "id": "A GUID",
      "application": "App type A",
      "body": "This is a test message...",
      "url": "http://www...",
      "datePublished": "2024-11-08T00:00:00.0000000Z"
    }
  }
}

I think I'm missing something basic, but I just can't see it.
Note, I don't have issues when the app is in foreground. The issue occurs in the Android emulator and my physical device (Pixel 7).
Environment, Nuget packages, and versions:

.NET MAUI - 8.0.82
Microsoft.Maui.Controls - 8.0.82
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility - 8.0.82
Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 124.0.0.1


This is not a .NET MAUI issue, Android does not share these values, if you click on a grouped notification, this is the expected behaviour, you should use your personal notifications API and check if there are any updates

@FreakyAli Could you please elaborate "you should use personal notifications API"? I'm not quite sure what you mean by that.

Don't you have a web-api layer that sends all notifications for the users? And if so don't you also have an API that gives you the list of all unread notifications for a user

@FreakyAli The app does not send any notifications. It only receives from Firebase

Can you get the items by using the if (intent?.Extras != null) instead of the if (intent?.HasExtra("body") == true) ?

@GuangyuBai-MSFT No. I still need to get the value from intent?.HasExtra("body"), so it doesn't really matter if I use intent?.Extras to check it.
